# How to duplicate a worksheet with its content with microsoft graph excel api

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-excel

i'm trying to duplicate a worksheet with its content into another new one.

In origin what i have is a table and i want to copy the worksheet with the table and its content.

In programming in PHP and i'm trying this:

```
$sheet = $graph->createRequest('GET', $originSheet)
        ->setReturnType(Model\WorkbookWorksheet::class)
        ->execute();

    $sheet->setName($worksheetName);

    
    $graph->createRequest('POST', $sheetUrl)
        ->setReturnType(Model\WorkbookWorksheet::class)
        ->attachBody($sheet)
        ->execute();
```

But the content is not duplicated, i just get a duplicated empty worksheet.

I tried to perform a GET to retrieve the origin table of origin worksheet, something like this:

```
$originSheetTables = $graph->createRequest('GET', $originSheetUrl)
        ->setReturnType(Model\WorkbookTable::class)
        ->execute();
```

But i don't know how to use the response of this request ($originSheetTables) to add into the new worksheet. I have tried this request with this approach:

```
$graph->createRequest('POST', $sheetUrl.'/'.$worksheetName.'/tables/add')
        ->attachBody($originSheetTables[0])          
        ->execute();
```

But i'm getting a 400 error: "The request URI is not valid. The segment 'add' must be the (truncated...)"

Could you help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can directly duplicate the whole worksheet with data in a single call but you can first [create a worksheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheetcollection-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request) and later [add a table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-post-tables?view=graph-rest-1.0#http-request) and then get data from the [previous worksheet table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/table-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: and then [add the values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/table-post-rows?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) as rows to the second table in second spread sheet.

Comment: moving this to answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly duplicate the whole worksheet with data in a single call but you can try a work around by first [creating a worksheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheetcollection-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request) and later [add a table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-post-tables?view=graph-rest-1.0#http-request) and then [get data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/table-list-rows?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) from the previous worksheet table
and then add the values as rows to the second table in second spread sheet.

If you want to have it done on a single call, you can raise a uservoice on the [Microsoft Graph Uservoice Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359629) for this feature.